# Trying to pre-fill text-tabs in Docusign via Rest API

Tags: php, json, rest, docusignapi

I am having problems prefilling textTabs for my server templates in my docusign console. My application generates an agreement on our end and is added as a composite template along with another form that is added as a server template with a template id.

The server template has several fields the user needs to be able to fill out. The tabs have been defined and added with the manage template tool in the docusign console.

I have no problems sending the documents and the signHereTab is the only one that is correctly added to the form.

The two problems I have are 1) the fields the user should fill out are never shown on the recieved document, 2) the prefill information I am sending is not received by docusign. Below is the body request I am sending to the docusign REST API:

```
{
   "emailSubject":"Nexogy Service Agreement Signature Request",
   "emailBlurb":"Thank you for your interest in our services. Please sign the following agreement to continue with your service installation.",
   "status":"sent",
   "emailSettings":{
      "replyEmailAddressOverride":"sales@nexogy.com",
      "replyEmailNameOverride":"Nexogy",
      "bccEmailAddresses":[

      ]
   },
   "eventNotification":{
      "url":"https:\/\/dna.local.com\/documents\/set-status",
      "loggingEnabled":true,
      "requireAcknowledgment":true,
      "useSoapInterface":false,
      "includeDocuments":false,
      "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField":true,
      "envelopeEvents":[
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Sent"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Signed"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Voided"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Declinded",
            "includeDocuments":true
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Completed",
            "includeDocuments":true
         }
      ]
   },
   "recipients":{
      "signers":[
         {
            "email":"mmoreno509@gmail.com",
            "name":"Test Tester",
            "roleName":"Signer1",
            "recipientId":718
         }
      ]
   },
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":1,
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "email":"mmoreno509@gmail.com",
                        "name":"Test Tester",
                        "roleName":"Signer1",
                        "recipientId":718,
                        "tabs":{
                           "signHereTabs":[
                              {
                                 "xPosition":100,
                                 "yPosition":205,
                                 "documentId":1,
                                 "pageNumber":6,
                                 "fontColor":"BrightBlue"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "documents":[
                  {
                     "documentId":1,
                     "name":"ChuyMPDFAgreement.pdf",
                     "remoteUrl":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/dna_local\/ChuyMPDFAgreement.pdf"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":2,
               "templateId":"ae435358-1410-40fd-803e-273028d19287",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "email":"mmoreno509@gmail.com",
                        "name":"Test Tester",
                        "roleName":"Signer1",
                        "recipientId":718,
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"Full Name",
                                 "value":"Test Tester",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":123123123,
                                 "value":123123123,
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"Address",
                                 "value":"Test",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"City",
                                 "value":"Hollywood",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"State",
                                 "value":"FL",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"ZipCode",
                                 "value":33081,
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"Country",
                                 "value":"US",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"Phone",
                                 "value":"3454657676",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"AccountName",
                                 "value":"Testing Company",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"\\*FullName",
                                 "value":"Test Tester",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":3,
               "templateId":"017d0d20-754b-4093-8896-ff1c00ee2cda",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "email":"mmoreno509@gmail.com",
                        "name":"Test Tester",
                        "roleName":"Signer1",
                        "recipientId":718,
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"AccountName",
                                 "value":"Testing Company",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":123123123,
                                 "value":123123123,
                                 "pageNumber":"2"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":4,
               "templateId":"11a88684-07ac-4ee5-9994-cb88635fb42f",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "email":"mmoreno509@gmail.com",
                        "name":"Test Tester",
                        "roleName":"Signer1",
                        "recipientId":718,
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"AccountName",
                                 "value":"Testing Company",
                                 "pageNumber":"2"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"Address",
                                 "value":"Test",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"City",
                                 "value":"Hollywood",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"State",
                                 "value":"FL",
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              },
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"ZipCode",
                                 "value":33081,
                                 "pageNumber":"1"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not update template tabs upon creation of the envelope at this time.

Your **signHereTabs** is in your **inlineTemplate**, which will add additional tags to your envelope.

If you want to update tabs that are contained in a template via the API, your workflow should look like:

1. Create Envelope - (`"status" : "created"`)
2. Modify Envelope - Edit tags here
3. Send Envelope

All of the documentation around building this workflow is located in [DocuSign REST API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf)

Comment: actually i found that if i have a composite template for each server template with an inline template to hold the tags worked just fine.